# How to add flag to Kubernetes controller manager

Tags: kubernetes, kube-controller-manager

I'm new to K8s. In process to config Openstack Cinder as K8s StorageClass, i have to add some flags to my kube controller manager, and I found that it's my big problem.
I'm using K8s 1.11 in VMs, and my K8s cluster has a kube-controller-manager pod, but I don't know how to add these flags to my kube-controller-manager. 
After hours search, i found that there's a lot of task require add flag to kube-controller-manager, but no exactly document guide me how to do that. Please share me the way to go over it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You can check `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` dir on your master nodes.
This dir would contain yaml files for master components.

These are also known as static pods.

More Info : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/static-pod/

Update these files and you would be able to see your changes as kubelet should restart the pod on file change.

As a more long term solution, you will need to incorporate the flags to the tooling that you use to generate your k8s cluster.

Comment: I used to get pod kube-controller-manager in yaml format, edit yaml file then apply but it fail. But your suggest worked. Thank you so much, you're the best :)

Comment: this was helpful!